# simulate a custom wireless mac protocol in omnet++

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am using Omnet++ to simulate a custom wireless mac protocol, I am fairly new to omnet so here is my question : 
can I customize my own nodes ( because I need simple module .cc files to implement the protocol ) and use Inet at the same time to define the characteristics of the channel ( using radiomedium ) ?

I have searched forums and basically anywhere I could look for answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can. The physical medium is handled by the XXXRadioMedium and the XXXRadio modules in INET. Independent of that, you can set your own MAC protocol. INET already has a lot of MAC protocols, but obviously you can implement your own in C++ and then configure the simulation to use that: I recommend you to take a look at the [INET Wireless Tutorial, especially Step 6](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/tutorials/wireless/doc/step6.html):

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am facing some difficulties on designing the node with simple module ( ao that I can have a .cc file to implement the behaviour ) and also including the inet parameters such as radio and radiomedium. Is there any way that I can discuss the issue and maybe get some help from you ?